# Pandas Conditional Creation for a multitude of dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a question which is closely related to this post: 
[Pandas conditional creation of a series/dataframe column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913659/pandas-conditional-creation-of-a-series-dataframe-column)

The difference to that question is that I would like to use the value of one column to assign the values in MANY other columns. I'd like to avoid writing a for-loop with many `if`-statements over all entries for efficiency reasons.

I have a dataset like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Type', 'Set', 'Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'color', 'number'])
df['Type'] = ['A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'C', 'D']
```

Which produces:

```py
  Type  Set   Q1   Q2   Q3 color number
0    A  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN
1    B  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN
2    B  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN
3    C  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN
4    D  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN
5    E  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN
6    C  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN
7    D  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN
```

Based on the information in `Type`, I want to create values for various other columns.

For example, for `Type==A`, I'd like a list of varying things to happen to the respective rows in the dataframe:
`df['Set'] = 'Z'`, `df[Q1]=0`, `df[Q2]=0`, `df[Q3]=random.choice(True, False)`, `df[color]='green'` and `df[number]=call_on_some_function_I_defined(input = df[Q1])`

When `Type==B`, I'd like certain other things to happen to those same variables: 
`df['Set'] = 'X'`, `df[Q1]=random.choice(0, 250, 500, 750, 1000)`, etc.

Ideally, I'd like do something along these lines:

```py
import numpy as np

conditions = [
    (df['Type'] == 'A'),
    (df['Type'] == 'B'),
    (df['Type'] == 'C')] #etc.
choices_A = [df['Set'] = 'Z', df[Q1]=0, df[Q2]=0, df[Q3]=random.choice(True, False), df[color]='green', df[number]=call_on_some_function_I_defined(input = df[Q1])]
choices_B = [df['Set'] = 'X', df[Q1]=random.choice(0, 250, 500, 750, 1000)` df[Q2]=random.choice(0, 250, 500, 750, 1000), df[Q3]=False, df[color]='red', df[number]=call_on_some_function_I_defined(input = df[Q2])]

df = np.select(condition[0], choices_A, default=0)
df = np.select(condition[1], choices_B, default=0)
```

To create output like:

```py
  Type  Set   Q1   Q2   Q3    color number
0    A   Z    0    0   True   green  17
1    B   X   750   0   False   red   85
2    B   X   500  250  False   red   93   #etc
```

While `numpy.select` with its `conditions` and `choices` is perfect for conditional assignment of values of a *single* dataframe column, I haven't found a neat way to make conditions work for assigning values to *multiple* dataframe columns.

Comment: This is a project, not a question.  You will need `if` statements in one form or another but it will require them none the less.  I understand that you want a better way but in my opinion, this is the wrong forum.

Comment: @piRSquared, I am confused as to why this question is too far off from this forum, because it appears to be a project to you. My question is about one or maybe two lines of code, namely whether there is some adjustment that I can make to `np.select` or I am missing a function which can do this sort of conditional statements applied to multiple columns at once.

Comment: It is my opinion that your question is asking too much at once.  That could be a result of your not providing a [mcve].  Regardless, I find the question confusing and too involved.  Rather than down voting the question or voting to close and walking away, I wanted to give you feedback so that you knew where I was coming from.  I'm just one person so you can ignore me if you like.  I'm just trying to be helpful.

Comment: If every row of the same type were the same, you could potentially get some speedup with builtin methods. Since every row is different (due to ``random`` depending on the type) this isn't a vectorisable/parallelisable operation, and you might just as well use a ``for`` loop. Random values are *very* expensive to create, the loop should not matter by itself. You might have some luck creating dataframes for each type separately, *then* merging them or selecting from them.

Comment: MisterMiyagi, Would you say that there is an option of making this work, if this dependency on previously calculated variables (such as `df[number]` being dependent on the `Q2` column) would not exist?